# Program crashes

Tags: c, recursion

Program -

Function that accepts current year and the birth year, computes the age

The problem -

Program crashes

The code-

```
int Age(int curr,  int birth)
{
if (curr > birth)
{
    return  1 + Age(curr--, birth);
}
return 0;
}
```

the input in function main is:

```
printf ("%d\n", Age(2014,1989));
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Crash or run infinitely? Change to `--curr`.

Comment: Why are you using recursion for a simple mathematical equation?

Comment: Why are you using `--`? The modified variable is never used afterwards. `cur-1` would completely be sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
... Age(--curr, birth);
```

as `curr` shall be decremented before `Age()` is being called.

<strike>Using `curr--` decrements `curr`</strike>  The decrement applied to `curr` by `curr--` takes effect after `Age()` returned, which will never happen, as the programm runs into a stack overflow due to trying infinit recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the help and why this happens if you can tell

Comment: "*... why this happens...*" why what happens? Did you noticed the update to my answer? Does this makes things clear?

Comment: Really, it should be `curr - 1`, there is no reason to use are or post decrement here.

Comment: The statement “Using `curr--` decrements `curr` after `Age()` returned” is not correct. The `--` is part of an expression in an argument to `Age`, and arguments are fully evaluated before a function is called. The **value** of the expression `curr--` is the value of `curr` before `--` is applied, but `curr` is modified before `Age` is called.

Comment: Hmm, yes, fair enough. @EricPostpischil So would my modified answer take this into account correctly?

Comment: No, I am sorry, the text is still not correct. The decrement to `curr` does in fact take place (in the C computation model) before `Age` is called. If `curr` were global and `Age` printed its value, the value printed by `Age` would show that `curr` has been decremented, even though the value of the parameter that `Age` receives does not contain the decrement.

Comment: Correct text would be “The decrement applied to `curr` by `curr--` does not affect the value used for the argument to `Age`. The value passed to `Age` is the value of `curr` before `curr` is decremented.”

Comment: Why use `--` at all? The modified variable is never used. Just use `curr-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could be simply done as

```
age = curr-birth-1
```

without worrying about recursion.

Comment: @alk - It does - This is the answer to the essence of the question. Why make life complicated?

Comment: @alk i was just making it easy for him to reduce the code. What u answered is the correct solution to his problem. curr-- is post decrement and hence will decrement curr after the execution of that statement.

Comment: @all: I just re-read the answer, and instantly deleted my comment. However "use recursion" probably was part of the assignment ...?

Comment: Usually with recursion either Rabbits or Fibonacci is involved

Answer (score 1):

In `curr--` you are doing post decremented, decrements will affect in next line. so the value passed to function is always same as `curr`, 
You should do '--curr' so it will decrements curr  value before calling of function.